# Default icons in CButtonColumn not showing

Tags: yii, icons, crud, cgridview, cbuttoncolumn

I use Yii and I generated CRUD using Gii called for a `Workers` model. Somehow I dont have built in icons for default actions (view, update, delete) when browsing records using `admin` action (Manage Workers). I tought it was caused by the fact that the crud&model are in the module but no - for a test I made same model & crud in main directory - result is the same.

How is that possible? How can I make those icons show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `columns` of `CGridView` have to contain `CButtonColumn`:

```
'columns'=>array(
   array(
      'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
   ),
 )
```

But you are right, this should have been generated by Gii.

Comment: Actually it is generated by Gii. The problem is that it's there but there are no buttons showing up.

Comment: Try deleting all the generated code and start over creating model and crud code.

Comment: Hah. It actually works! Pretty weird - I copied previous code and then compared using total commander - perfectly the same. Still - the second version works :/ Mysteries of Yii ;) Thanks though. I'll mark it as a solution.